How to resolve content provider authority conflicts in Android Manifest for package name app.digiedu.android
Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name app.digiedu.android.
Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.example.app.androidx-startup, com.example.app.provider.
is showing when i am updating the app in play store my client has upload the app with app generator but now i have build it with kotlin
i changed my directory name from file from com->example->android to app->digiedu->android also i changed the application id from com.example.app to app.digiedu.android also in prvider i did the same changes but it still showing this error also i change the imports as well i don't know what else to do

Press ctrl shift F (or command shift F if you use macos). Then find com.example.android . change everything named like that to app.digiedu.android
